# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Bullet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, constants

I have a very annoying problem with my migrations.

First the Errormessage:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32:in `<module:AltSystem>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32:in `<module:AltSystem>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:960:in `<module:FileUtils>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:962:in `<module:FileUtils>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:965:in `<module:FileUtils>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:966:in `<module:FileUtils>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /Users/agstwn/Documents/WORK/hq_git/PS)
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Bullet
```

Here's my --trace:

```
/config/initializers/const_missing.rb:12:in `const_missing_with_csv_export'
    /config/environments/development.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    /Users/agstwn/Documents/WORK/hq_git/PS/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea with this, i had search it but i can't find it. maybe you guys now about this?

**/config/initializers/const_missing.rb**

```
class << Object 

  def const_missing_with_csv_export(name) 
    if name.to_s =~ /^(?<resource_name_camelcase>.+)Csv(?:Import|Export)(?:Log|Job)/ 
      const_get $~['resource_name_camelcase'] + 'Controller' 
      const_get name 
    else 
      const_missing_without_csv_export(name) 
    end 
  end

  alias_method_chain :const_missing, :csv_export 
end
```

Comment: Bullet is a gem that helps determine when to use eager loading effectively.

Do you have any code related to Bullet in an initializer or any of the environment files?

Comment: Whats in this file?  `config/environment.rb` (specifically line 12) Do you mention Bullet?  If so, do you have the Bullet gem installed?

Comment: i dont mentioned it in environment.rb but i have installed bullet gem.

Comment: it's `PublisServer::Application.initialize!` in line 12. @GraemeMcLean

Comment: Could you also share `/config/initializers/const_missing.rb` and your `Gemfile` please.

Comment: Oke Here it's: 
Oke Here it is:
class << Object

  def const_missing_with_csv_export(name)
    if name.to_s =~ /^(?<resource_name_camelcase>.+)Csv(?:Import|Export)(?:Log|Job)/
      const_get $~['resource_name_camelcase'] + 'Controller' 
      const_get name                                         
    else
      const_missing_without_csv_export(name)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :const_missing, :csv_export
enda

Sorry for bad typing, i dont know how to make it good. @GraemeMcLean

Comment: When you add source, please edit your question instead of including it in a comment - it's much easier to read :)  Now, could you also add '/config/environments/development.rb' (highlighting line 49) and `Gemfile` please. Your error suggests you are missing the `Bullet` gem.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran `bundle install` before, it said that a gem in development didn't install.

I re-ran bundle install again, and that made sure that my bullet gem was installed.